# Problem with version MQTT

Tags: raspbian, mqtt

I am not a linux person. I know enough to break things.

I have a pi, MQTT is working perfectly on that I set up all though I do not remember the exact steps (probably a lot of unneeded ones included).

Problem is a serial program I need reboots the pi then it locks it up before it finishes rebooting. I thought it was just my program, but then another (supposedly working) program did the same thing so I started suspecting linux.

I upgraded linux. It never booted again.

So I started fresh. Latest linux (rasbian in all cases) locks up, never finished booting.  I dropped back a release.  Ok finally, a working Pi again.

Same MQTT program refuses to run and I have tried everything I can think of.  Restored an old back up image.  Yes, my MQTT clients are fine, but the serial port program is critical.

So it could be many things and I have no idea where to start. What is preventing a working MQTT client from connecting mosquitto mqtt broker? And assuming I am willing to try to same thing I had to do on the OS, drop back a version (or 2 or 3) what command even does that?  I looked into apt-get, but apparently old versions are not kept track of on the Pi.

Update: thanks Joan, not quite what I am looking for.  I am looking for someone who knows the protocols and what changes have been made in the last 3-4 months that would break a working system.  Initial digging looks like a message from the client is now expecting a response, and never receives it.  Apparently the same message did not expect a response before (or something like that).

Comment: To install MQTT an invocation such as sudo apt-get install mosquitto is all you need to do.

Comment: "refuses to run" -- are there any messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have an old version of mosquitto installed on your Pi. The version in the raspbian wheezy repository is very old - 0.15, compared to the most recent 1.4.2 release.

If you want to install a more recent version, the best bet is to use the mosquitto debian repository, located at repo.mosquitto.org.

To do this, you could run the following steps (taken from http://jpmens.net/2013/09/01/installing-mosquitto-on-a-raspberry-pi/ ):

```
curl -O http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
sudo apt-key add mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
rm mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo curl -O http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-wheezy.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
```

If you're not using the wheezy version of raspbian, then replace it with `jessie` above in the line starting `curl`

The reason that the old version wouldn't work with a new client is that there is a more recent version of the MQTT protocol (v3.1.1) that the old broker doesn't understand. Because it doesn't understand, it disconnects any clients that are using it.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. In fact I did try something like this, but I think it might have been a different repo, and it failed. I will try again following this and let you know. thanks much.

Comment: That did indeed work. I just checked and that was the one I tried before. I must of mis-fingered something, or failed to restart or something user stupid. thanks again.

Comment: sorry, was doing that and got into 3 other things before I finished.  Also word of warning, a plain upgrade is what wiped out my Pi to begin with. I would NOT trust the current repo for a full upgrade.  I used the install approach (and included mosquitto-clients python-mosquitto)